# link to itunes (itms://...) without opening a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, itunes

how do i call a link to itunes (itms://...) without opening a new window.
with window.open there comes a new window (as the function says :))
$.get('itms://...'); doesn't work.

Any other possibilitys :)?

would be thankful for help!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try, but two ideas come to mind:

1. iframe
2. set `location` to the URL, it shouldn't replace your page anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you are referring to not opening a new browser window, as opposed to trying to open iTunes within the browser.

In that case, [Nickolay's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618928/js-link-to-itunes-itms-without-opening-a-new-window/1618963#1618963) 2nd option is your best bet - this JavaScript will work (using actual example URL):

```
var url = 'itms://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=307538288';
location.href = url;
```